# Laravel shopping cart (5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I'm using eclipse PDT, with CodeMix, Terminal+, Composer, and symphony. I created a Laravel project and in my `composer.json` I have the following dependencies:

```
"require" : {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "cyvelnet/laravel5-fractal": "^2.3",
        "darryldecode/cart": "~4.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/fractal": "^0.18.0",
        "ssheduardo/redsys-laravel": "~1.3.0"
    },
```

I also added in my `app.php` both the service provider

```
'providers' => [

        #Lots of other providers here
        Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,
],
```

and the facade alias

```
'aliases' => [

        #lots of other aliases
        'Cart' => Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade::class

    ],
```

I even published the provider `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

But somehow whenever I try to include the thing in any of my files either with `use \Cart;`, `use \Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade;` or `use \Darryldecode\Cart\Cart;` it gives me a

> The import whichever one I'm using cannot be resolved

Already tried clearing the cache, closing, and opening eclipse, deleting the project from the workspace and starting it again, uninstalling and reinstalling the cart and I don't know what else to do. Also tried Gloudemans instead and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Don't really know what you're talking about, just followed the README, and haven't done any coding

Answer (score 1):

Just using

```
'Cart' =>  Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::class,
```

instead of

```
'Cart' => Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade::class
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to find that either. Also did you mean Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::class or with the quotation marks?

Comment: Nope, I cannot use it still

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually adding the vendor folder to the builpath, foir some strange reason composer wasn't adding it.